# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, .htaccess, cors, preflight

I am working with an Angular 2 & Ionic 2 app. I had to change to another server for testing and the API has stopped working with the below error message:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

I added this to .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

This on my angular provider:

```
  loginUser(data): Observable<any> {
    let username: string = data.username;
    let password: string = data.password;
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    let url = this.domain + "/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?context=edit";
    let bt = btoa(username + ":" + password);

    this.storage.save('bt', {'bt':bt});
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + bt);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json())
  }
```

Also, enabled a chrome plugin I have for CORS issues which is enabled and works on other cases when I am on localhost projects.

I tried everything I found and I am not sure what else I could do.

Checking the network tab on Chrome Dev Console, the response is this one:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
You do not have permission to access this document.
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>
Web Server at my domain here
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Based on the answers, this is my rewrite rules aswell:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: From what you have provided I see you are doing fine from front end perspective. Something is going wrong with the back end service. You know 403 HTTP code is used for 'Forbidden' so you are not allowed to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you still have that chrome plugin enabled, you need to disable it, and leave it off. Because otherwise it’s just going to be interfering with your troubleshooting

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can actually navigate directly to that `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?context=edit` in a browser without also getting a 403 when you try that? Because it’s possible the configuration problem has nothing to do with the preflight OPTIONS but instead you’ll get it regardless of what type of HTTP method is used to request that URL. That is, it could be that your Apache config is basically just doing a 'deny all' for any request for that URL. The details in the question don’t indicate whether or not that’s the case.

Answer (score 2):

The 403 response status indicates a general problem with the server backend not being configured to handle `OPTIONS` requests, including [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

The server must respond to `OPTIONS` requests with a 2xx success status—typically 200 or 204.

If the server doesn’t do that, and your request in one that triggers browsers to do a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), then it makes no difference what `Access-Control-*` headers you have it configured to respond with—because if the preflight fails, the browser stops right there and never moves on to doing the `GET` request the code snippet in the question is meant to send.

In the case of code snippet in the question, the `Authorization` header that code’s adding is what triggers the browser to do a preflight, and what requires the server to handle the `OPTIONS` request.

The answer to configuring the server to handle `OPTIONS` requests in the right way—to send a 200 or 204 success message—depends on what server software it’s running. The question indicates the server’s running Apache, so you can try adding this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

---

**Update**

If you have something in your `.htaccess` that’s restricting access to `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me` in some way, you need to wrap that in `<LimitExcept OPTIONS>…</LimitExcept>`; for example:

```
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: So I see you the bit to your .htaccess for handling the OPTIONS request. Are you still getting a 403 after adding that? If so, and you have some other code in your .htaccess that’s restricting access to the the /wp-json/wp/v2/users/me route, then you need to make it not restrict access to it for OPTIONS requests (but instead I guess only for GET requests). As far authentication, one point to be clear on is that the browser doesn’t send the Authorization request header when it makes the OPTIONS request. So the OPTIONS request must work without that Authorization header being needed.

Comment: The .htaccess is exactly the same in both servers. But you might be correct on another part. I checked the network tab and there isn't the Basic Authentication on the request headers.

Comment: For another suggestion about how to make sure things work correctly for OPTIONS request, see the update added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

`HttpOptions` does not append authorization to the request, you need to use `AllowAnonymous` on the Options endpoints

Comment: I am not familiar a lot with server side settings. Can you please copy paste the .htaccess from above and replace the part you are referring to?

Answer (score -1):

You can get through this very easy! Let's follow me right now

1. Create a shortcut on your desktop
   [image]
2. Right-click on the shortcut and click Properties
   [image]
3. Edit the Target property

[image]

4. Set it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --5. disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:/ChromeDevSession"
   [image]
5. In VIsual Studio Code, run ionic serve -l
   [image]
6. You're gonna see new tab open http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab. You should be aware that this link is opened in the normal chrome tab, not the "disable-web-security" chrome we have set up.
   [image]
7. Double click to the shortcut that we have set up to open the "disable-web-security" chrome tab. Then paste http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab into this tab.
   [image]

So the reason that we get multiple errors when working with woo-commerce-api is this "web-security" by Google. Then you just disable it and you actually don't need any CORS Extensions. So remove them right now if you have installed.

And this solution i write for people who learn this course https://www.udemy.com/ionic-3-apps-for-woocommerce-build-an-ecommerce-mobile-app/. This is an ionic e-commerce app that using woo-commerce-api to set and get data from Wordpress (local or live server). If you have trouble in other language not ionic, it still works fine.

Actually i have done a lot of searchings on Google to find this solution. I hope this helps all of you. Now, i need to go to bed because tomorrow i have a final report about this ionic project with my lecturer

See ya!
Quy Le

Comment: this is a solution for a client-side problem, this one is server-side

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. So how can I delete this answer, @Heady?